# Android: Restricting devices of particular resolution from downloading the app from play store

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, android-resolution

I have a app which I am **supporting for following resolutions** only:

1. 1280X800(Nexus7)
2. 1024X600(Samsung tab2)
3. 1280X800(Samsung Tablet 10”)
4. 1280X720(S3, Micromax HD)
5. 1920X1080(S4, HTC 0ne)

Now, I want the rest of the android devices whose resolution is not in the above list to be not able to download the app. How can I do that in the manifest file?

Comment: "I have a app which I am supporting for following resolutions only" -- that is akin to writing a Web app only for browser windows sized to 941 x 675 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest you **can't** do it.

You can allow this devices on Google Play account. Devices that are not listed can't be download apk. For example, look at the screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: i added the screen-shot, this menu showed after you upload your apk